# getChildView (for BaseExpandableListAdapter) not working properly

Tags: android, spinner, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView`. The xml for the Child rows looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_child"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number_input_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/temp_txt" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number_input_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Basically, my `getChildView` looks like this:

```
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_child, viewGroup, false);
    }      
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_1);
    spinner.setAdapter(mUnitsCA);
    spinner.setSelection(14);  // 14 is a test
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(mSpinnerListener);

    return view;
}
```

This should ensure that item number 14 in spinner_1 is selected every time. Some of the time this works, but often it selects the first item in the spinner instead. I can't work out where this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: One recommendation I found was to change `setSelection()` to the following: `spinner.setSelection(14, true);`. Have you tried this?

Comment: Wow, yes this did the trick! Thank you. Incidentally, the second parameter can be true or false and it still works. Just seems like the single parameter version of 'setSelection' is buggy.

Comment: Um, new to this website, how do I mark the above comment as answered?

Comment: Hah, that's interesting... You can't accept comments so I'll post my comment as an answer so you can accept. Just click the green check. Thanks. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One recommendation I found was to change `setSelection()` to the following:

```
spinner.setSelection(14, true);
```

---

**Edit:** *(Building upon my answer for future seekers)*

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int,%20boolean%29) seems to be very vague on this, simply stating the following:

```
setSelection(int position, boolean animate);
//Jump directly to a specific item in the adapter data.
```

In my research it seems that many have had the same issues and from what I can tell declaring the animation `boolean` seems to be necessary more often then not, whether it be true or false. Maybe only custom animations or declared animation's require a `boolean` value of `true` in order to animate but not having an animation will accept either `true` or `false`...